# Safety of opening .txt files

Tags: text-files, virus

If I'm given a URL that points to a `.txt` file, is it always safe to open it? Can it possibly contain virus or malicious content?

Comment: Are you asking as a user? If you are then you're on the wrong forum. If you're asking as a programmer, then I'm no expert on operating systems, but I think it's _your_ responsability to read from the file safely.

Comment: This isn't really related to programming, so you might want to ask this on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A genuine txt-file can contain virus code but it cannot be executed, so it's totally safe. However, a file can use double file extension like this, so watch out:

a-virus-file.txt.exe

Windows hides by default .exe because it's a known file type.

Comment: If it is a URL, why would the extension be hidden?

Answer (score 3):

It is not safe to rely solely on a file extension. The real file type can easily be masked by someone changing the extension, so the file could easily be a virus or malicious content.

For example:

MyVirus.exe -> SeeminglyHarmlessFile.txt

Comment: This answer is rather.. confusing.  You should specify, given there are two questions in the OP, not one.

Comment: @Daedalus The one question answers the other - since it could contain a virus, it is not always safe to open it.

Comment: Not what I meant; the first question is, 'is it safe to open x', you reply 'absolutely' without specifying which you are replying to.